# Authentication at CUPS web interface

Tags: 11.04, authentication, printing

When I try to perform any administrative task on CUPS [web interface](http://localhost:631/)
I get pop-up window that requires me to authenticate at CUPS. Authenticating both as root and as a my user fail, even though my user is added to the **lpadmin** group as described in:

[CUPS Print Server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/cups.html)

Any idea what can be wrong or how I debug it?

Comment: Could you attach the `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` file? Make sure that your user account has a password set.

Comment: [cupsd.conf](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B8Kfjcz6AcfCMjU0MjJjYjMtMTViOS00N2JmLThmOTAtOWJhMDQ5ZWE1ZmFl&hl=en_US)  

my account has a password set

Answer (score 3):

Comparing your cups.conf file, I only see a few differences:

- You've replaced `Port 631` by `Listen localhost:631` to prevent remote administration
- You've removed `Allow @LOCAL` three times:

  ```
   DefaultAuthType Basic
   <Location />
     Order allow,deny
  -  Allow @LOCAL
   </Location>
   <Location /admin>
     Order allow,deny
  -  Allow @LOCAL
   </Location>
   <Location /admin/conf>
     AuthType Default
     Require user @SYSTEM
     Order allow,deny
  -  Allow @LOCAL
   </Location>
  ```

Re-add those lines or you'll be unable to open CUPS. After adding yourself to the `lpadmin` group, you need to restart CUPS due to the way groups work. That can be done with:

```
sudo restart cups
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the change did not help  

My guess is that the issue is related to the PAM configuration.  

I'll going to explore this direction

Comment: If it's related to PAM, you should check `/var/log/auth.log`. Otherwise, CUPS logs are in `/var/log/cups/`

Comment: sudo usermod -a -G lpadmin <myuser> helped me. (as mentioned by Lekensteyn)

Answer (score 2):

According to this post: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.printing.cups.general/28081, it could come from the fact that you have several instances of CUPS running.

Check it by using this command:

```
ps -e | grep -U cups
```

If you find two instances, kill them using:
*(sudo is required since cups is run at the root level)*

```
sudo kill -9 {pid}
```

With **{pid}** being number of the instances given by the **ps** command.

Then restart cups:

```
sudo restart cups
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Now, it's `# systemctl restart cups.service`  Your answer worked for me; thanks.